# repeating-linear-gradient background at the top is moved

Tags: css

Recently I was trying my best to make a simplistic stripped background for my website, when making the stripes using the repeating-linear-gradient text in css I found that at the top of the page their was a slight issue. It has one 'block' moved to the side.
I dont know if its due to my monitor or it's an actual issue but I would appreciate any help possible,
Code Found below.

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
to right,
#141517,
#141517 30px,
#1d1f21 30px,
#1d1f21 40px );
```

Your's, 
David.

Comment: Other than the fact the colors are super dark this seems fine. can you post a screenshot or sqlfiddle of the issue?

Comment: Yeah, everything looks good here: https://jsfiddle.net/cu8vt7uy/

Comment: Sadly I think it might be due to my browser, but I'm not completely sure. http://imgs.beastfox.com/aXsCWvTzH6.png

Comment: @BeastFox can you share a sqlfiddle? hve you tried another browser?

Comment: I'll share a fiddle but currently I haven't setup an SQL Database with it so i'll just send a fiddle that contains the css and html. https://jsfiddle.net/o3k8wmwt/

Comment: I think it's due to the text boxes if i'm correct?

Comment: I've worked it out! It was due to an unneeded <p> element. Thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to a non needed

element
I simply removed it to fix the issue.

The element looked like this.

```
    <p class="made-by"></p>
```